# Module::Build Build issue

Tags: perl, build, module-build

What is the output of building a perl module using  `Module::build`.

I don't know how to make reuse of that. help me to resolve this issue (Again I got the the same code inside `blib->lib` directory.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish and how you need to "reuse it"?

Answer (score 0):

`Module::Build` gathers files and information from your module and creates a blib folder where it stages the files that will be installed in your system when you use `Build install`. That said, that folder is only a way of `Module::Build` (and `ExtUtils::MakeMaker` and others) store the finals that should be installed between the calls of `make` and `make install` (or `Build` and `Build install`). These files are also used during the run of `make test` or `Build test`.

Not sure if this helps.